# Casecading dropdownlist in ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created a cascading dropdown list in ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC. When I choose a category from the first dropdown list according to this choice sub-category is displayed is the second dropdown list. I have used jQuery for this and it is working fine. But when the value is not entering in the database even values from other dropdown lists are also not entering the database here is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(state).attr('disable', 'true')
    $(city).attr('disable', 'true')

    $(category).attr('disable', 'true')
    $(subCategory).attr('disable', 'true')

    LoadStates();
    LoadCategory();

    $('#category').change(function () {
        var categoryId = $(this).val();
        if (categoryId > 0) {
            LoadSubCategory(categoryId);
        }
        else {
            alert("Select Category");
            $(subCategory).empty();
            $(subCategory).attr('disable', 'true')
            $('#subCategory').append('<option>--Select Sub Category--</option>');
        }
    });
    $('#state').change(function () {
        var stateId = $(this).val();
        if (stateId > 0) {
            LoadCities(stateId);
        }
        else {
            alert("Select State");
            $(city).empty();
            $(city).attr('disable', 'true')
            $('#city').append('<option>--Select City--</option>');
        }
    });
});

function LoadStates() {
    $('#state').empty();
    $('#city').empty();
    $('#city').attr('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/PropertListing/GetStates',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response != undefined && response.length > 0) {
                $('#state').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#state').append(' <option>--Select State--</option>');
                $('#city').append('<option>--Select City--</option>');
                $.each(response, function (i, data) {
                    $('#state').append('<option value=' + data.stateId + '>' + data.stateName + '</option>');
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#state').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#city').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#state').append('<option>--States not available--</option>');
                $('#city').append('<option>--Cities not available--</option>');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}

function LoadCities(stateId) {
    $('#city').empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/PropertListing/GetCities?id=' + stateId,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response != undefined && response.length > 0) {
                $('#city').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#city').append('<option>--Select City--</option>');
                $.each(response, function (i, data) {
                    $('#city').append('<option value=' + data.id + '>' + data.cityName + '</option>');
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#city').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#city').append('<option>--Cities not available--</option>');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}

function LoadCategory() {
    $('#category').empty();
    $('#subCategory').empty();
    $('#subCategory').attr('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/PropertListing/GetCategory',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response != undefined && response.length > 0) {
                $('#category').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#category').append(' <option>--Select Category--</option>');
                $('#subCategory').append('<option>--Select Sub Category--</option>');
                $.each(response, function (i, data) {
                    $('#category').append('<option value=' + data.categoryId + '>' + data.propertyCategoryName + '</option>');
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#category').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#subCategory').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#category').append('<option>--Category not available--</option>');
                $('#subCategory').append('<option>--Sub Category not available--</option>');
            }
        },

        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}

function LoadSubCategory(categoryId) {
    $('#subCategory').empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/PropertListing/GetSubCategory?id=' + categoryId,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response != undefined && response.length > 0) {
                $('#subCategory').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#subCategory').append('<option>--Select Sub Category--</option>');
                $.each(response, function (i, data) {
                    $('#subCategory').append('<option value=' + data.id + '>' + data.subCategoryName + '</option>');
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#subCategory').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#subCategory').append('<option>--Sub Category not available--</option>');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the markup in `index.cshtml`:

```
<div class="col">
    <label>Category</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="category" style="background-color: transparent;" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories"></select>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <label>Sub Category</label>
    <select id="subCategory" class="form-control" style="background-color: transparent;" asp-items=" ViewBag.subCategories"></select>
</div>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/casecadingddl.js"></script>
```

And the controller code is:

```
public JsonResult GetCategory()
{
     var categories = _context.PropertyCategories.ToList();
     ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(categories, "CategoryId", "PropertyCategoryName");
     return new JsonResult(categories);
}

public JsonResult GetSubCategory(int id)
{
     var subCategories = _context.PropertySubCategories.Where(x=>x.SubCategoryId == id).OrderBy(x=>x.SubCategoryName).ToList();
     ViewBag.subCategories = new SelectList(subCategories, "SubCategoryId", "SubCategoryName");
     return new JsonResult(subCategories);
}
```

Why are the values of the dropdown list not entered in the database?

Comment: What you mean about not entering the database? Do you mean the ajax call not successfully get the json result from the database?

Comment: No Ajax call is working means when the form is loaded for entry I am successfully choosing a category and according to it sub-category is shown it is working. But after entering other fields like product name etc.  and submit the form all the data is entered in the database except categoryID and subCategoryID is shownng null. Besides that I have one more dropdown in the form and value of that dropdown is allso null in the database

Comment: Could you please share your submit codes and backend method codes?